# PLB or satphone rental in the USA from National Forest offices or ranger stations?

Tags: united-states, personal-locator-beacons, satellite-phones

I've read that in the United States, national forests, ranger offices, etc. often have some safety-related equipment for rent, such as bear canisters.  Do they rent out Personal Locator Beacons, satellite phones, or similar equipment that can be used to call for help in the wild?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't rent that kind of equipment at a Park Service ranger station. They only rent out bear canisters, and even that is only at certain locations (e.g., Yosemite Valley). If you want a Spot or a PLB, you just need to buy one.

Comment: Surely there are commercial places that rent them out?  I've always rented in Sweden...

Comment: That may be possible, but then why not rent in Sweden for your trip to California?

Comment: I'll be in the US for a month but only hiking for 5 days, so then I'll need to rent it much longer than I need to.  I might just stick with telling a source where I go and when I should be back, though.

Comment: There are indeed commercial rental options (e.g. https://www.lowergear.com/ out of Arizona).  They ship the units via UPS, so you'd need to place your order well in advance.

Comment: @requiem I know this is old, but please make your comment into an answer. If you don't, I might copy/paste it into an answer, but you should take the credit.